# Set focus on a div in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a javascript function that displays the div that I am hiding, I am wondering how I then setfocus on the div so it goes down right to it on the page. I say setfocus because I have tried it earlier but it didnt work. Here is the function and the idea of focusing that i have.

```
<script>
function toggle_travelarea(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
    document.getElementById("canada").style.display = 'none';   
    document.getElementById("asia").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("australia").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("newzealand").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("africa").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("usa").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("samerica").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("europe").style.display = 'none';
        e.style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementByClassName('slidedeck').focus()
    }
</script>
```

area i want to set focus to!

```
<div class="slidedeck">
```

Comment: When you say setfocus, do you mean scrollTo()? Get the position of the element and pass the top position to scrollTo(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollTo

Comment: I think this is what you want, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: Yes the div is just under it but I want the page to set that div at the top. I tried adding in this but still didnt work.
 var xpos= document.getElementById(id).value;
   var ypos= document.getElementById(id).value;
window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos);

Comment: i am not using jquery on this page for the scrolltop

Comment: don't forget to accept if you'll find any answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

Actually thought this didnt work but used an href to the anchor div id and then an onclick for the function and it worked properly. Thanks for the input everyone

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to do a bit with math and use scrollTo.
Here's example -> http://jsbin.com/epozur/4

Basically:

HTML

```
<div id="hidden">
</div>
<button id="show">show</button>
```

JS

```
var btn = document.getElementById('show'),
    hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  hidden.style.display = 'block';
  scrollTo(0, hidden.offsetTop);
});
```

That should give you idea how to go further.

mz